# VBA Not detecting Spaces Present in Text for Determining Hierarchy

Tags: excel, vba, data-cleaning

I am VBA writing code to clean up data that has its hierarchy indicated by the number of spaces at the beginning of item name within a column but they are all in the same column (see Below).

```
    Project B
            Implementation
                    AB - Item 1
                    BK - Item 2
                    CC - Item 3
                    CM - Item 4
                    SR - Environmental/R
```

Desired format after cleaning:

```
Project B  |  Implementation | AB - Item 1

Project B  |  Implementation | BK - Item 2

Project B  |  Implementation |CC - Item 3

Project B  |  Implementation |CM - Item 4

Project B  |  Implementation | SR - Environmental
```

VBA seems to be unable to detect all the spaces at the beginning and so I have not been able to automate the sorting without using find and replace approach first to prepare the data for cleaning.

See code used below after the range has been selected. Note, that this code works when the spaces are replaced with symbols ["(P)", "(I)", "(S)"] using find/replace and then using those symbols in the if statements instead of the "         ".

```
For i = 1 To NumRow
        If InStr(b_Range.Value2(i, 1), "                ") <> 0 Then
            b(k, 1) = Replace(b_Range.Value2(i, 1), "                ", "")
        ElseIf InStr(b_Range.Value2(i, 1), "            ") <> 0 Then
            b(k, 2) = Replace(b_Range.Value2(i, 1), "            ", "")
        ElseIf InStr(b_Range.Value2(i, 1), "    ") <> 0 Then
            b(k, 3) = Replace(b_Range.Value2(i, 1), "    ", "")
            
            For j = 1 To NumCol - 1
                A(k, j) = CDbl(b_Range.Value2(i, 1 + j))
            Next j
            k = k + 1
            b(k, 1) = b(k - 1, 1)
            b(k, 2) = b(k - 1, 2)
        End If
Next i
```

Let me know your thoughts!

Comment: Are you certain your "spaces" are actual spaces, and not something that looks like a space?   Try outputting the character codes for each character in the cell (use a loop with `Mid()` and `Asc()` ) and see if you're getting what you'd expect.  Space should be 32

Comment: Hi Tim, yup, I am getting 32 for all chars in the beginning of the cells using the mid and asc functions. Any suggestions?

Code used to check manually

msg = Asc(Mid(b_Range.Value2(2, 1), 1, 1))

MsgBox msg

Answer (score 0):

Using your posted data this works for me:

```vb
Sub Tester()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, c As Range, rng As Range, arr, proj, impl, rw As Long, v
    
    Set rng = Selection                     'for example
    ReDim arr(1 To rng.Rows.Count, 1 To 3)  'size the output array
    proj = ""
    impl = ""
    rw = 0
    For Each c In Selection.Cells
        v = c.value
        Select Case Len(v) - Len(LTrim(v)) '# of leading spaces
            Case 4: proj = Trim(v)  'or a range (eg) Case 3 To 7
            Case 12: impl = Trim(v)
            Case 20
                rw = rw + 1
                arr(rw, 1) = proj
                arr(rw, 2) = impl
                arr(rw, 3) = Trim(v)
        End Select
    Next c
    
    Range("D1").Resize(rw, 3).value = arr 'output the results array 
End Sub
```

Input/Output:
[image]